# how to login from a rest api using angularJS and ionic

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

so i have this mobile app that uses ionic framework, and for the authentification, i want to get the emails stored in the database using a rest api, my problem is i dont know how to code the function that will verify the informations entered by the user, i'm pretty sure ive done a chaotic login function down here... so here's how services.js look like

```
 .factory('UserService', function($q) {

        var users={};
    var url="http://localhost/test/index2.php";

      if(url.indexOf("localhost") >= 0)
          {
      jQuery.ajax({
          contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
              type: "GET",
             dataType: "jsonp",
             crossDomain: true,
             url: url,
             success: function(data, status, jqXHR){ 

                  users=(data);
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, status) {
              // gestion d'erreur
              alert(status);
              alert(jqXHR.status);

          }
  });
    }else
        {
        jQuery.ajax({
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  type: "GET",
                 dataType: "json",
                 crossDomain: true,
                  url: url,
                  success: function(data, status, jqXHR){ 

                      users=(data);

              },
              error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                  // gestion d'erreur
                  alert(status);
                  alert(jqXHR.status);

              }
      });
        }



return {
        login: function (email,pwd) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                results = users.filter(function (element) {
                    return (email === element.email and pwd === element.pwd);
                });
            deferred.resolve(results);
            return deferred.promise;
        }





    }

});
```

and here's my api

```
  <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "imane", "annuaire");
   $r = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM employee");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    if($_GET['callback']) {
            $json = json_encode($result);
            header("Content-type: application/javascript");
            print $_GET['callback'] . '('.$json.')';
    } 
    else
    {
            header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
            echo json_encode($result);
    }               

   }    
   ?>
```

thank you!

Comment: Check [this](https://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/) awesome tutorial for login authentication.

Comment: thank you for the link..but i dont know how can this really help me..it uses different technologies you see..